# .js file not stored in package contents

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I am using .js file to validate .html file in my application,the .js&.html files added in my project,but the .js file not stored in package contents,only contains the .html file,I am using ios simulator 5.0,

my validation source is..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *urlAddress        = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                                                  ofType:@"html"]; //you can also use PDF files
    NSLog(@"%@",urlAddress);
    NSURL *url                  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj    = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:requestObj];
    web.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}

- (IBAction)markHighlightedString:(id)sender {

    // The JS File   
    NSString *filePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HighlightedString" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
    NSData *fileData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *jsString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // The JS Function
    NSString *startSearch   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stylizeHighlightedString()"];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

}

- (IBAction)getHighlightedString:(id)sender {


    // The JS File   
    NSString *filePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HighlightedString" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
    NSData *fileData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *jsString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // The JS Function
    NSString *startSearch   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getHighlightedString()"];
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

    NSString *selectedText   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"selectedText"];
    NSString * highlightedString = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:selectedText];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Highlighted String" 
                                                    message:highlightedString
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Oh Yeah" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    //[alert release]; // not required anymore because of ARC
}
- (IBAction)removeAllHighlights
{
    // calls the javascript function to remove html highlights
    [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}
```

I am getting null value in  NSLog(@"%@",filePath);//HighlightedString.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but could it be that you haven't copied that file to the target's output? Or, that you're using an out-dated version of the app that's being run? An easy fix might be just to do a Clean and then a Build and Run. Also, the file might be not be set to go into the target. You can change that by going to Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. This will bring up an area where you can add that file.

Following that, I usually do a Clean and then a Build just to make sure I'm getting a new version of the application.

***Addition***

Also, you might try setting the `inDirectory:` part of the method where you're setting `filePath` to `nil` instead of specifying an empty string. Or, you could just get rid of that altogether and `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HighlightedString" ofType:@"js"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two options

1- click on js file in the project navigator then in the properties you needd to check a check box to include it in the build. This image I made before check step one and four only.

[image]

2- just write the JavaScript into the HTML file and put it inside function and call this function and stop loading it as text. So stringByEval.... Will take the JavaScript function only.